# There are two logs in the path in file_path, and I want to read each of them using python

Tags: python, glob

There are a,b,c,d folders in the D:\Coding\iroiro\ChuckRep folder, and there are also e,f,g,h folders in it. And there are C000 logs and W logs in this e,f,g,h folder, and I want to bring them in individually, but I don't know if the code I designed is wrong or nothing.

```
file_path = './ChuckRep/*/*/'
file_name, ext = os.path.splitext(file_path)

for path in glob.glob(file_path):
    if ext=='.smm_logs':
        cfile_path = glob.glob(file_name[:-4]+'C000.smm_logs')[0]
        wfile_paths = glob.glob(file_name[:-4]+'*W*.smm_logs')
        print(cfile_path)
```

How can I print cfile_path and wfile_path to get the result?

Comment: What exactly do you expect `file_name, ext = os.path.splitext(file_path)` does, especially since you just set `file_path = './ChuckRep/*/*/'`? This will never be true `ext=='.smm_logs'`, so the rest of your code does not run.

Comment: file_name, ext = os.path.splitext (file_path) is to split each log file name to distinguish between the c-log and the w-log that I want to find.

Comment: I changed the code a little bit.

Comment: I only want to get files with c000.smm_logs when I print(cfile_path) and w.smm_logs files when I print(wfile_path).

Comment: You cannot expect a command to work before there is data for it to operate on. You call `os.path.splitext()` on the directory name/mask alone, but you expect a result for each individual file - that won't work. Without meaning any disrespect, you should probably look at a few tutorials, or play around with these individual commands to gain a better understanding of how they work and go together. Your small bit of code contains many problems, too many to address in a single question without clear focus.

Answer (score 0):

1. If you expand your `file_path` glob-like, you get only directories.
2. You try to split extension from a glob pattern string before expansion, which doesn't make sense.
3. Instead I suggest you start with using [`os.walk()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/os.html#os.walk), I'd say it's less confusing for beginner.